# ProRes in Premiere - no audio

Tags: premiere, editing, final-cut-pro, cs5

I'm experimenting with switching from Final Cut to Premiere.

However, most of my source material is ProRes.

When I drag a ProRes Quicktime into Premiere (after setting up a new 'custom setting' to match), I do not get any audio playback!

Other formats work fine.

Is there a workaround for this?

(I have FCP installed on the same machine, so I have all the codecs; and the video plays back perfectly, actually more smoothly than in FCP. Just no audio!)

UPDATE: The ProRes I was trying to play had 4 audio tracks; 2 stereo and 2 mono. When I stripped out 3 of the tracks and left just 1 stereo track, it worked fine.

Is there any way around this? I need to work with 100-minute files of feature films that have separate tracks for Dialog, Music, Effects...

Thanks!